# Convergence of a power series at the edges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am given the following:

$ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^{a+\sin a}} (x-1)^n $ .

I know that the series converges for $x\in (0,2)$ .

I now need to :

1. Show that there exists an $0<a<1$ for which the series converges at both 0 and 2
2. Show that there exists an $0<a<1$ for which the series converges only in one of the edges (i.e. 0 xor 2) .

I know that from Leibnitz alternating signs test, the series will always converge for $x=0$ . But how can I generate one that won't (or will) converge at $x=2$ ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x = 2$, the series is

$$ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^{a+\sin a}} $$

and we know this will converge ($p-$series test) if and only if $a + \sin a$ > 1.

Further, $0 + \sin(0) - 1 = -1 < 0$ and $1 + \sin(1) - 1 = \sin(1) > 0$ so by the intermediate-value theorem you will be able to find some values of $a \in (0,1)$ that fit your requirements (note: invoking IVT is not necessary, you can just find/guess some values of $a$, this is just to assure you it's possible).

Comment: You're welcome!